# On Linux, is root privilege required to send a wake-on-lan magic packet?

Tags: linux, root, wake-on-lan, magic-packet

On Linux, is root privilege required to send a wake-on-lan magic packet?

If it depends on how you send the magic packet, please let me know under what situation root is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the program you use to send wake-on-lan packets.  Some programs use raw packets, and therefore require root.  Other programs embed the magic wakeup sequence in a bog standard UDP packet, and thus do not require root.

In theory it shouldn't matter what kind of packet you use, as long as there's the magic wake-on-lan sequence somewhere inside it.  In practice I seem to remember that my old desktop refused to wake up when I used a Python script that sent UDP packets, but worked fine if I used a C program that used raw packets.

Comment: I see. So if a WoL program requires root the reason is that it sends raw packets. Thanks! And just a quick check: sending packets to the broadcast address doesn't need root, right?